# Изменение картины ImageView после паузы

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

У меня обычная игра на память. 12 квадратов и под ними картины Нажал на квадрат, открылась картина, потом на еще один квадрат, если 2 картины одинаковые, квадраты остаются откытыми, а если не одинаковые, после короткой паузы оба квадрата закрываются. Проблема в том, что при неодинаковых картинах никакой паузы не происходит. Попробовал и Thread.sleep(500).
Код ниже.
При четном количестве нажатий количество попыток увеличивается на 1. Equal-количество взаиморавных рисунков, если выше 1-го, то попытка удачная и оба квадрата открываются без проблем, а если нет, то тут проблема: второй квадрат так и не открывается, а оба квадрата закрываются.

```
if (clicks % 2 == 0) {
        attempts++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            int equal = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (imageViews[i].getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(imageViews[j].getDrawable().getConstantState()))
                    equal++;
            }
            if (equal > 1) {
                imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(imageViews[i].getDrawable());
            } else {
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(imageViews[i].getDrawable());
                imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qm));
            }
        }
    }
    opened = 0;
```

Как сделать видимым и "неправильный" рисунок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае `Thread.sleep(500);` вешает UI и поэтому Вы не видите картинки. Ну и остальное. Вынесите обработку в отдельный поток/используйте `Handler` / `AsyncTask`. К примеру:

```
if (clicks % 2 == 0) {
    attempts++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        int equal = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            if (imageViews[i].getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(imageViews[j].getDrawable().getConstantState()))
                equal++;
        }
        if (equal > 1) {
            imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(imageViews[i].getDrawable());
        } else {
            final Handler handler = new Handler(); //Потом правильно сделать Handler
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qm));
                }
            }, 500);
            imageViews[i].setImageDrawable(imageViews[i].getDrawable());
        }
    }
}
opened = 0;
```